# Second Order Linear DE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, derivatives, exponential-function

$$
y''+ 3y' - 4y = e^x + 5xe^{-4x}
$$
What would the particular integral be?

I'm using the method of undetermined coefficients. I've tried to guess so my possible solutions but none of them satisfy the equation.

e.g. $y_p = xe^x + e^{-4x}(Ax + B)$ ---- this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that $1$ and $-4$ are solutions of the characteristic equation. Therefore you should try with 
$$y_p(x) = Cxe^x + xe^{-4x}(Ax + B).$$
After the substitution we find that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$5Ce^x+(2A-5B-10Ax)e^{-4x}=e^x + 5xe^{-4x}$$
which holds iff 
$$5C=1,\quad -10A=5,\quad 2A-5B=0.$$

Comment: But you've got 3 unknowns, so how would you solve to find each of them? I have ended up with 2 equation: 1) in terms of C. 2) in terms of A & B.

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED Note that these equations should be verified for all x. See my edited answer.

Comment: thank you! so is there a general method I could use to figure out the particular integral? except from using variation of parameters.

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED The general rule is the following: if $f(x)=\exp(ax)P(x)$ with $P$ a polynomial of degree $n$, then a $y_p(x)=x^m \exp(ax)Q(x)$ where $Q$ is a generic polynomial of degree $n$ and $m$ is the order of $a$ as a solution of the characteristic equation. 

P.S. The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted" http://math.stackexchange.com/tour